# JavaFX selecting value in ComboBox throws IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, scenebuilder

I am having issues with selecting a value in the ComboBox. I get a IndexOutOfBoundsException when a value is selected.

I have tried changing the for loop and it did not work. The values in the combobox also seem to repeat multiple times.

Can someone suggest what the issue is?

```
package edu.unlv.mis768.project;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AddOption1Controller {
      @FXML
        private Button CancelButton;

        @FXML
        private RadioButton ExistingCragRadioButton;

        @FXML
        private RadioButton NewCragRadioButton;

        @FXML
        private ToggleGroup NewExistingCrag;

        @FXML
        private Button NextButton;
        
        @FXML
        private TableView<ClimbingCrag> cragTableView;

        @FXML
        private ComboBox<ClimbingCrag> existingCragComboBox;
       
    /**
     * this method will initialize the scene to have the correct values for the crag choice list
     */
    public void initialize() {
        existingCragComboBox.setDisable(true);
        // Create an instance of the DAO implementation class
        CragDAO cragDAO = new CragDAOImpl();
        
        // Call the getAllCragNames() method to retrieve the list of crags
        List<ClimbingCrag> cragList = cragDAO.getAllCragNames();
        
        // Clear the existing items in the choice box
        existingCragComboBox.getItems().clear();
        
        // Loop through the cragList and add the string representation of each object to the choice box
        System.out.print(cragList.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < cragList.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("here");
                existingCragComboBox.getItems().addAll(cragList);
            }
        }
```

```
package edu.unlv.mis768.project;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class CragDAOImpl implements CragDAO {
    
@Override
public List<ClimbingCrag> getAllCragNames() {
    // Create a array list for the data.//defined as the superclass List so we can display on GUI like observable list
    List<ClimbingCrag> cragList = new ArrayList<ClimbingCrag>();
    
    try {
        Connection conn = RockClimbingUtil.getDBConnection();
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(
                ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        
        //String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + DBConstants.CRAG_TABLE_NAME;
        String sql = "SELECT "+ DBConstants.CRAG_PK_NAME+ " FROM " + DBConstants.CRAG_TABLE_NAME;
        //Execute the query.
        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        
        //Get the number of rows.
        result.last();                 // Move to last row
        int numRows = result.getRow(); // Get row number
        result.first();                // Move to first row

        for (int row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
            // create a new object and fill the field with the values from the result set.
            ClimbingCrag aCrag = new ClimbingCrag(result.getString("Name"));
            
            //Add the object to the list
            cragList.add(aCrag);

           // Go to the next row in the ResultSet.
           result.next(); 
        } 
        // close the database connection
        
            stmt.close();
            RockClimbingUtil.closeDBConnection(conn);
   
            
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    // return the result
    return cragList;
}
```

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: [ fromIndex: 0, toIndex: 1, size: 0 ]
    at javafx.controls@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.subList(ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.java:171)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/javafx.collections.ListChangeListener$Change.getAddedSubList(ListChangeListener.java:243)
    at javafx.controls@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ListViewBehavior.lambda$new$57(ListViewBehavior.java:292)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:239)
    at javafx.controls@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.callObservers(ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.java:110)
    at javafx.controls@19.0.2.1/javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.clearAndSelect(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:394)
    at javafx.controls@19.0.2.1/javafx.scene.control.ListView$ListViewBitSetSelectionModel.clearAndSelect(ListView.java:1452)
    at javafx.controls@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.simpleSelect(CellBehaviorBase.java:282)
    at javafx.controls@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.doSelect(CellBehaviorBase.java:246)
    at javafx.controls@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.mousePressed(CellBehaviorBase.java:176)
    at javafx.controls@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3894)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1887)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2620)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

FXML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="502.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="edu.unlv.mis768.project.AddOption1Controller">
   <children>
      <ImageView fitHeight="200.0" fitWidth="502.0" layoutY="-1.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@Half_Dome.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Label layoutX="38.0" layoutY="234.0" text="Please Select New or Existing Crag:" />
      <RadioButton fx:id="NewCragRadioButton" layoutX="38.0" layoutY="272.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#radioButtonListener" text="New Crag">
         <toggleGroup>
            <ToggleGroup fx:id="NewExistingCrag" />
         </toggleGroup>
      </RadioButton>
      <RadioButton fx:id="ExistingCragRadioButton" layoutX="141.0" layoutY="272.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#radioButtonListener" text="Existing Crag" toggleGroup="$NewExistingCrag" />
      <Button fx:id="CancelButton" layoutX="336.0" layoutY="532.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#changeSceneToMainMenu" text="Cancel" />
      <Button fx:id="NextButton" layoutX="420.0" layoutY="532.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#nextButtonListener" text="Next" />
      <Label layoutX="190.0" layoutY="64.0" prefHeight="69.0" prefWidth="122.0" text="Crux" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="48.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <ComboBox fx:id="existingCragComboBox" layoutX="261.0" layoutY="268.0" onAction="#initialize" prefWidth="150.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

We tried changing the for loop and we got the same error

Comment: So `initialize` is called when the `ComboBox` is used/an element is selected and not when the scene is created? Does adding `existingCragComboBox.getSelectionModel().clearSelection()` change anything?

Comment: You are adding the entire list to the combo box once for every element of the list. So if the list contains five elements, for example, the whole list will be repeated in the combo box five times. You just need `existingCragComboBox.getItems().addAll(cragList)` without the `for` loop. I don’t know if that will fix the problem, but having the same object in the combo box multiple times may confuse things.

Comment: @dan1st *” So initialize is called when the ComboBox is used/an element is selected and not when the scene is created?”*. No, the `initialize()` method is only called (by default) once, when the FXML is loaded.

Comment: @James_D so what's the `onAction="#initialize"` in the FXML?

Comment: @dan1st _so what's the onAction="#initialize" in the FXML?_ utter nonsense (to put it bluntly)

Comment: @dan1st Oh, yes, I did not see that. That’s actually the cause of the problem; clearing the items list will cause the list of selected items to be cleared, and doing that while the selected item is changing will cause the index out of bounds exception.  It makes absolutely no sense whatsoever to have the `initialize` method as an event handler. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

### The problem

When inspecting the stack trace, it seems like it's only JavaFX specific code. One seemingly interesting line is

> javafx.controls@19.0.2.1/javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.clearAndSelect(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:394)

So the error seems to occur when selecting something.

It seems like you are calling `initialize` when using your `ComboBox` by putting `onAction="#initialize"` in your code.

So, when selecting an element, it would execute the `initialize` method. This would remove the elements and possibly add some again.

Since you selected an element but that element is no longer present, it throws the exception when attempting to access the selected element

### Don't call `initialize`

From the name `initialize`, I assume that it should only be called when scene is loaded. If you remove `onAction="#initialize"` from your FXML file, that would no longer happen.

### Other problems

As [@James_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189127/james-d) mentioned [in the comments of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76087094/javafx-selecting-value-in-combobox-throws-indexoutofboundsexception?noredirect=1#comment134186835_76087094), you are calling `addAll` in a loop with the same elements. This would add the same elements multiple times. Assuming you don't want that, remove the loop and only keep the body of the loop.

Comment: I haven’t tested it, but I think clearing the selection in response to an action event in the combo box would cause the same issue. (I *think* the exception actually occurs *because* the selection is cleared, indirectly by clearing the entire items list.)

Comment: I tested it and you are correct. I thought the issue was because it had a selected and clearing the selection would fix this but after testing, it seems that clearing the selection actually causes the error (I removed that part/thank you for telling me about that).